# How to specify dictionary parameter in dJango urls?

Tags: django

I am newbie to Django and got the following error saying that

`Reverse for 'plot_graph' with keyword arguments '{'column': '["c4", "c5"]'}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[0-9]+)$', 'index/api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\\w-]+)/$']`

My webpage shows me five distinct checkboxes which are `c1,c2,c3,c4,c5` and when I click `c4,c5` and then click submit button, I can see the above error.

below are my files.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^form/$', views.Form),
    # url(r'^api/plot_graph/', views.plot_graph, name='plot_graph'),
    url(r'^api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[\w-]+)/$', views.plot_graph, name='plot_graph'),
    url(r'^api/plot_graph/(?P<column>[0-9]+)$', views.plot_graph, name='plot_graph'),
```

**views.py**

```
def plot_graph(request,column):
    print(column)

    data = Data.objects.all() \
        .extra(select={'data': connections[Data.objects.db].ops.date_trunc_sql('data', column)}) \
        .values(column)


    return JsonResponse(list(data),safe=False)


def Form(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if len(request.FILES) !=0:
            file = request.FILES['files']
            column_name = upload_file_name(file)
            return render(request,"index/form.html",{"column_name":column_name})
        else:
            columns = request.POST.getlist('columns')
            column_json = json.dumps(columns)
            return render(request,"index/form.html",{"column_json":column_json})
    else:
        return render(request,"index/form.html",{})
```

**form.html**

```
d3.json("{% url "plot_graph" column=column_json|safe %}", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d){
    d.c5 = d.c5;
});
```

In my case, how to change the urls so that it works?

Comment: That's not a thing that makes sense. Why do you want to use the full column_json variable in the URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `{{column_json}}` has context such as c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 and such values will be used for `plot_graph` as argument. The reason is that I don't know how to use variable in `{{column_json}}`in order to pass it into `d3.json("~~~") as argument. For example, in html, when I coded the `var data = {{column_json}}` and used the `data` for `d3.json("{% url "plot_graph" column=data %}",` then it didn't work.

Comment: You passes json as part of url (`api/plot_graph/{some_json: some_value}`).
But your view (`def Form(request)`) expects json in body of request, not in url. First of all you should choose: send json as part of url or as part of request body. I think you should choose body to send json to server. So, you should pass json somewhere in your function `d3.json`, but not as url. Tell, please, what variable d3 is? So I or someone else can tell you how to send json in body of request.
And, if you will send json in body, you will should modify your urls: `^api/plot_graph/$`, for example.